# how to send mails with a .Net app, via Outlook

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, outlook, ms-office

I'm new in web development and would like to add a feature to a project I'm working on.

I'd like to send emails with this project, and also to have a kind of agenda.

I'm already using outlook for the mails and the agenda. The thing I'd like is to have a kind of template. I've got it difficult to explain what I'm looking for, as far as I'm not a native english speaker.

So, let's have an example :
I'd like to develop customer loyalty. So, I'd like to send mails to a few customers (maximum 10 mails sent per offer).
In the view, I'll have to make a research on a keyword, which will return a list of customers. I'd like to have, next to each client, a hyperlink called "mail", wich would open Outlook, with the mail that's allmost fullfilled (with the name of the guy I'm mailing).
Is it possible to do this like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I am not 100% positive what and how you're trying to accomplish, and because Outlook is an email client app, I'll assume, that the website user is going to click the link and use Outlook. In that case the answer to your question is right under your nose :-) - examine the "Share a link to this question via [email](http://mailto:?subject=Stack%20Overflow%20Question&body=how%20to%20send%20mails%20with%20a%20.Net%20app,%20via%20Outlook%0Ahttps://stackoverflow.com/q/9802078/365968?sem=2)" on this very page - it uses a "mailto" tag.

Comment: Yes, I've found that it was pretty easy to send an email. I didn't know that I was allowed to parameter the mailto in order to get the body of the mail inside the mailto tag. Is it possible to do the same thing to have a meeting request?